# iOS Detects beacons for a short time only

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am using the core location framework to detect beacons in my App. I register the beacon region with a specific Proximity UUID.

```
    uuidString = "74278bda-b644-4520-8f0c-720eaf059935"
    beaconRegionIdentifier = "ios.test"
    beaconUUID = UUID(uuidString: uuidString)
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID!, identifier: beaconRegionIdentifier)
```

and then implement the following **CLLocationManagerDelegate** methods

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

    manager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)
    print(region)
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    print("Detected a beacon")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    ...
   // Ranging beacons here

    print(beacons)
}
```

The log that I am getting is this:

```
[CLBeacon (uuid:74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:200, minor:51, proximity:1 +/- 0.17m, rssi:-45)]
[CLBeacon (uuid:74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:200, minor:51, proximity:1 +/- 0.17m, rssi:-45)]
[CLBeacon (uuid:74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:200, minor:51, proximity:0 +/- -1.00m, rssi:0)]
[CLBeacon (uuid:74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:200, minor:51, proximity:0 +/- -1.00m, rssi:0)]
[]
[]
[]
```

i.e The ***didRangeBeacons*** method detects the beacon for only once then suddenly the [CLBeacon] array becomes empty even though the beacon is transmitting data packets the entire time.

Can someone please explain this strange behaviour?

PS: Once the app is in the background state, the beacons are detected perfectly. These logs are only seen when the app is in foreground

**TL;DR**
iOS beacon app not detecting beacons properly in foreground.

**EDIT**

The beacons use the same code for detecting in background, i.e. foreground and background detection is done using the same functions. I just request additional time from iOS to scan beacons in background

```
func extendBackgroundTime() {
    if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        return
    }
    let self_terminate = false
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "RangeBeacons", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        print("Background Task Terminated By iOS")
        if self_terminate {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
            self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you using a real beacon or you are simulating it using another device ?

Comment: I'm currently simulating it using my other phone

Comment: can you use other devices with other beacon apps, or try to use a real beacon.

Comment: Yeah I can do that. But it's pretty erratic, first I thought the no of packets transmitted might be less, but even if I set the packet frequency at 10Hz then also, it behaves the same and sometimes does not even detect the beacon.

Comment: The second two log lines that say, `-1.00m, rssi:0` indicate that the beacon was not detected in that ranging cycle either.   CoreLocation ranging keeps including beacons that are not detected in a ranging cycle for a few seconds after they disappear and sets the rssi to 0 and the accuracy to -1 to indicate that.  So this means your app only detected the beacon for two cycles (2.0 secs).  How are you detecting the beacons in the background (iOS usually limits you to 5 secs of this?)  I wonder if your setup for background detection is somehow breaking foreground detection.